# Can I create a backup of a specific partition and restore it later?

Tags: time-machine, backup, partition, restore

I have my beta partition on my SSD and I want to create a backup of it so I can identically restore it on a different partition, later.

My simple question is: Can I?

I've got multiple partitions and I thought I'd create a time machine backup of that partition solely, excluding all different partitions, and then on a later moment have a fresh partition and restore that time machine backup.

But, it's the first time I would use TimeMachine to actually restore a backup, so.. I want to ask you guys, beforehand.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use every HDD for time machine except the system HDD, but if you partition ate your system HDD you can use the new time machine for Time Machine.
Remember: don0t format all your HDD when formatting, you will format even your backup!

Comment: Huh.. no no no no. I'm creating a TimeMachine backup on my NAS, which creates a backup of my OS X beta partition. I'm currently on the official 10.10.3 and I want to have a backup of that partition/installation and was wondering if I create a new partition later on if I could simply restore that installation on that specific partition. With other words: Can I create a backup, delete the partition and restore it later when I want?

Comment: oops ok! You can create a backup, delete the partition and restore it later when you want; that's the scope of time machine! I'm not sure that you can do that with beta OS X versions...

Comment: A backup is a backup, eh ;)